# Use of unresolved identifier in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an if statement or a switch statement and created a variable to be used.

```
    if (randomIcon == 1) {
        var coolCircle = TapCircleIcon(typeOfCircle: CircleType.Circle1)
    }

    addChild(coolCircle)
```

The issue I get is unresolved identifier for coolCircle. This is kind of expected, but I am not sure what the swift equvilant would be.

In Obj-C I would probably set the pointer to nil, then create it if the value exists. How would I get this to parse correctly in Swift. What should I do to set the variable to TapCircleIcon class, but not create an object until the if/switch statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler:

```
if (randomIcon == 1) {
    let coolCircle = TapCircleIcon(typeOfCircle: CircleType.Circle1)
    addChild(coolCircle)
}
```

More flexible:

```
let coolCircle: TapCircleIcon?
if (randomIcon == 1) {
    coolCircle = TapCircleIcon(typeOfCircle: CircleType.Circle1)
}
else {
    coolCircle = nil  // or something else
}

if let coolCircle = coolCircle {  // not nil
   addChild(coolCircle)
}
```

Comment: In second example you can move code from else block to the very first line.

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv please explain further. Could you edit the answer with your suggestion?

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv no you can't do this. `let` implies that the variable can be assigned only once.

Comment: @fluidsonic, Yes, sorry, I meant var instead. But now I see why did you write with else. Good decision.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers don't explain anything:

You declare the variable `coolCircle` inside the `if` block which makes it available to that `if` block **only**. That means you will not be able to use it outside again. 
I would go with what @fluidsonic's answer to fix the problem.

Hope that helps your understanding :)